# Stream received doesn't have consistent video track

Tags: video, ffmpeg, streaming, flv

I'm streaming a video to a streaming engine (nginx-rtmp) using ffmpeg using the following command:

`ffmpeg -re -fflags +genpts -stream_loop -1 -i Sintel.mp4 -c copy -f flv rtmp://stream-engine/myStream`

However when I'm doing an `ffprobe` of this stream, directly to the streaming engine, sometimes there is no video in the stream.

The command to test the stream: `ffprobe -loglevel 'debug' rtmp://stream-engine/mystream`

95% I get the following output:

`ffprobe version 3.0.2 Copyright (c) 2007-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.38)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.0.2 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-opencl --enable-libx264 --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libxvid --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-vda
  libavutil      55. 17.103 / 55. 17.103
  libavcodec     57. 24.102 / 57. 24.102
  libavformat    57. 25.100 / 57. 25.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
  libavfilter     6. 31.100 /  6. 31.100
  libavresample   3.  0.  0 /  3.  0.  0
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
[rtmp @ 0x7ff57e4028a0] No default whitelist set
[tcp @ 0x7ff57e402d40] No default whitelist set
[rtmp @ 0x7ff57e4028a0] Handshaking...
[rtmp @ 0x7ff57e4028a0] Type answer 3
[rtmp @ 0x7ff57e4028a0] Server version 13.14.10.13
[rtmp @ 0x7ff57e4028a0] Proto = rtmp, path = /source/myStream, app = source, fname = myStream
[rtmp @ 0x7ff57e4028a0] Server bandwidth = 5000000
[rtmp @ 0x7ff57e4028a0] Client bandwidth = 5000000
[rtmp @ 0x7ff57e4028a0] New incoming chunk size = 4096
[rtmp @ 0x7ff57e4028a0] Creating stream...
[rtmp @ 0x7ff57e4028a0] Sending play command for 'myStream'
[flv @ 0x7ff57f002e00] Format flv probed with size=2048 and score=100
[flv @ 0x7ff57f002e00] Before avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 13 bytes read:2266 seeks:0
[flv @ 0x7ff57f002e00] Unknown type |RtmpSampleAccess
[flv @ 0x7ff57f002e00] video stream discovered after head already parsed
[h264 @ 0x7ff580000000] no picture
[flv @ 0x7ff57f002e00] All info found
[flv @ 0x7ff57f002e00] rfps: 23.750000 0.014474
[flv @ 0x7ff57f002e00] rfps: 23.833333 0.006451
    Last message repeated 1 times
[flv @ 0x7ff57f002e00] rfps: 23.916667 0.001640
    Last message repeated 1 times
[flv @ 0x7ff57f002e00] rfps: 24.000000 0.000043
[flv @ 0x7ff57f002e00] rfps: 24.083333 0.001659
    Last message repeated 1 times
[flv @ 0x7ff57f002e00] rfps: 24.166667 0.006488
    Last message repeated 1 times
[flv @ 0x7ff57f002e00] rfps: 24.250000 0.014530
[flv @ 0x7ff57f002e00] rfps: 48.000000 0.000173
[flv @ 0x7ff57f002e00] rfps: 120.000000 0.001079
[flv @ 0x7ff57f002e00] rfps: 240.000000 0.004316
[flv @ 0x7ff57f002e00] rfps: 23.976024 0.000173
    Last message repeated 1 times
[flv @ 0x7ff57f002e00] rfps: 47.952048 0.000694
    Last message repeated 1 times
[flv @ 0x7ff57f002e00] After avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 345943 bytes read:345943 seeks:0 frames:256
Input #0, flv, from 'rtmp://stream-engine/myStream':
  Metadata:
    Server          : NGINX RTMP (github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module)
    displayWidth    : 1280
    displayHeight   : 544
    fps             : 24
    profile         :
    level           :
  Duration: 00:00:00.00, start: 186.878000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0, 215, 1/1000: Audio: aac (LC), 48000 Hz, 5.1, fltp, 128 kb/s
    Stream #0:1, 41, 1/1000: Video: h264 (High), 4 reference frames, yuv420p(left), 1280x544 [SAR 1:1 DAR 40:17], 1/48, 24.42 fps, 24 tbr, 1k tbn, 48 tbc
detected 4 logical cores
[AVIOContext @ 0x7ff57e60cec0] Statistics: 345943 bytes read, 0 seeks
[rtmp @ 0x7ff57e4028a0] Deleting stream...`

Which is all fine, I get both video and audio tracks.

5% of the time I get the following:

`ffprobe version 3.0.2 Copyright (c) 2007-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.38)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.0.2 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-opencl --enable-libx264 --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libxvid --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-vda
  libavutil      55. 17.103 / 55. 17.103
  libavcodec     57. 24.102 / 57. 24.102
  libavformat    57. 25.100 / 57. 25.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
  libavfilter     6. 31.100 /  6. 31.100
  libavresample   3.  0.  0 /  3.  0.  0
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
[rtmp @ 0x7fe5cb407900] No default whitelist set
[tcp @ 0x7fe5cb408100] No default whitelist set
[rtmp @ 0x7fe5cb407900] Handshaking...
[rtmp @ 0x7fe5cb407900] Type answer 3
[rtmp @ 0x7fe5cb407900] Server version 13.14.10.13
[rtmp @ 0x7fe5cb407900] Proto = rtmp, path = /source/myStream, app = source, fname = myStream
[rtmp @ 0x7fe5cb407900] Server bandwidth = 5000000
[rtmp @ 0x7fe5cb407900] Client bandwidth = 5000000
[rtmp @ 0x7fe5cb407900] New incoming chunk size = 4096
[rtmp @ 0x7fe5cb407900] Creating stream...
[rtmp @ 0x7fe5cb407900] Sending play command for 'myStream'
[flv @ 0x7fe5cb800a00] Format flv probed with size=2048 and score=100
[flv @ 0x7fe5cb800a00] Before avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 13 bytes read:2288 seeks:0
[flv @ 0x7fe5cb800a00] Unknown type |RtmpSampleAccess
[flv @ 0x7fe5cb800a00] max_analyze_duration 5000000 reached at 5019000 microseconds st:0
[flv @ 0x7fe5cb800a00] After avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 87188 bytes read:87188 seeks:0 frames:241
Input #0, flv, from 'rtmp://stream-engine/myStream':
  Metadata:
    Server          : NGINX RTMP (github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module)
    displayWidth    : 1280
    displayHeight   : 544
    fps             : 24
    profile         :
    level           :
  Duration: 00:00:00.00, start: 343.593000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0, 241, 1/1000: Audio: aac (LC), 48000 Hz, 5.1, fltp, 128 kb/s
[AVIOContext @ 0x7fe5cb604480] Statistics: 87188 bytes read, 0 seeks
[rtmp @ 0x7fe5cb407900] Deleting stream...`

We tried many options, many encoders. We reproduced it with different stream source (ffmpeg, wowzaGoCoder, wirecast) and different streaming engine (wowza, nginx-rtmp). Some configurations make it harder to reproduce but still happens...

How can it be that the same stream can have a video track "sometimes" ?
What are we missing ?
How can we make it more resilient to such (very frustrating) bug ?

**Edit:**

If we record the stream, and if it doesn't detect the video track, the log displays after a while that the video track is detected but since the recording already started without it, the recorded stream has no video track.

Log of stream recording `ffmpeg -loglevel debug -y -i rtmp://stream-engine/myStream -c copy -f flv output.flv`:

`ffmpeg version 3.0.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.38)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.0.2 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-opencl --enable-libx264 --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libxvid --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-vda
  libavutil      55. 17.103 / 55. 17.103
  libavcodec     57. 24.102 / 57. 24.102
  libavformat    57. 25.100 / 57. 25.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
  libavfilter     6. 31.100 /  6. 31.100
  libavresample   3.  0.  0 /  3.  0.  0
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Splitting the commandline.
Reading option '-loglevel' ... matched as option 'loglevel' (set logging level) with argument 'debug'.
Reading option '-y' ... matched as option 'y' (overwrite output files) with argument '1'.
Reading option '-i' ... matched as input file with argument 'rtmp://stream-engine/myStream'.
Reading option '-c' ... matched as option 'c' (codec name) with argument 'copy'.
Reading option '-f' ... matched as option 'f' (force format) with argument 'flv'.
Reading option 'output.flv' ... matched as output file.
Finished splitting the commandline.
Parsing a group of options: global .
Applying option loglevel (set logging level) with argument debug.
Applying option y (overwrite output files) with argument 1.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Parsing a group of options: input file rtmp://stream-engine/myStream.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an input file: rtmp://stream-engine/myStream.
[rtmp @ 0x7fa1a5d00c60] No default whitelist set
[tcp @ 0x7fa1a5c0dac0] No default whitelist set
[rtmp @ 0x7fa1a5d00c60] Handshaking...
[rtmp @ 0x7fa1a5d00c60] Type answer 3
[rtmp @ 0x7fa1a5d00c60] Server version 13.14.10.13
[rtmp @ 0x7fa1a5d00c60] Proto = rtmp, path = /source/S1IwVWndb, app = source, fname = S1IwVWndb
[rtmp @ 0x7fa1a5d00c60] Server bandwidth = 5000000
[rtmp @ 0x7fa1a5d00c60] Client bandwidth = 5000000
[rtmp @ 0x7fa1a5d00c60] New incoming chunk size = 4096
[rtmp @ 0x7fa1a5d00c60] Creating stream...
[rtmp @ 0x7fa1a5d00c60] Sending play command for 'S1IwVWndb'
[flv @ 0x7fa1a6801200] Format flv probed with size=2048 and score=100
[flv @ 0x7fa1a6801200] Before avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 13 bytes read:2271 seeks:0
[flv @ 0x7fa1a6801200] Unknown type |RtmpSampleAccess
[flv @ 0x7fa1a6801200] max_analyze_duration 5000000 reached at 5019000 microseconds st:0
[flv @ 0x7fa1a6801200] After avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 87184 bytes read:87184 seeks:0 frames:241
Input #0, flv, from 'rtmp://stream-engine/myStream':
  Metadata:
    Server          : NGINX RTMP (github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module)
    displayWidth    : 1280
    displayHeight   : 544
    fps             : 24
    profile         :
    level           :
  Duration: 00:00:00.00, start: 344.126000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0, 241, 1/1000: Audio: aac (LC), 48000 Hz, 5.1, fltp, 128 kb/s
Successfully opened the file.
Parsing a group of options: output file output.flv.
Applying option c (codec name) with argument copy.
Applying option f (force format) with argument flv.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an output file: output.flv.
[file @ 0x7fa1a5c1cec0] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
Successfully opened the file.
Output #0, flv, to 'output.flv':
  Metadata:
    Server          : NGINX RTMP (github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module)
    displayWidth    : 1280
    displayHeight   : 544
    fps             : 24
    profile         :
    level           :
    encoder         : Lavf57.25.100
    Stream #0:0, 0, 1/1000: Audio: aac (LC) ([10][0][0][0] / 0x000A), 48000 Hz, 5.1, 128 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[flv @ 0x7fa1a6801200] video stream discovered after head already parsed
[flv @ 0x7fa1a6801200] New video stream 0:1 at pos:144269 and DTS:352.667s
size=     371kB time=00:00:22.57 bitrate= 134.6kbits/s speed= 1.3x
video:0kB audio:353kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 5.082170%
Input file #0 (rtmp://stream-engine/myStream):
  Input stream #0:0 (audio): 1058 packets read (361263 bytes);
  Total: 1058 packets (361263 bytes) demuxed
Output file #0 (output.flv):
  Output stream #0:0 (audio): 1058 packets muxed (361263 bytes);
  Total: 1058 packets (361263 bytes) muxed
0 frames successfully decoded, 0 decoding errors
[AVIOContext @ 0x7fa1a5c1cf80] Statistics: 3 seeks, 1061 writeouts
[AVIOContext @ 0x7fa1a5d00fa0] Statistics: 2401247 bytes read, 0 seeks
[rtmp @ 0x7fa1a5d00c60] Deleting stream..`

Comment: Try the detection with `-analyzeduration 20M -probesize 20M` placed before `-i ...`

Comment: Also, stream_loop can be unreliable and can create gaps in tmestamps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to mulvya comment : [Stream received doesn't have consistent video track](https://superuser.com/questions/1243898/stream-received-doesnt-have-consistent-video-track?noredirect=1#comment1824450_1243898) , increasing the value of analyzeduration and probesize gives more chances to ffmpeg to detect all the informations it needs to correctly process the stream.

Default value based on ffmpeg documentation: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#Format-Options are:

- 5s for analyze duration
- 5 MB for probe size

Which for high quality stream is not enough.